# XSS in Rails' JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, escaping, backbone.js

I'm rendering content using Backbone in Rails. Some of the json properties i'm getting from the models will be html attributes, some of them might be used inside the javascript and others will be inserted between html elements. All of these require different escaping mechanisms, how do people deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our project we are using [doT templates](http://olado.github.com/doT/) which (as most other) allow for interpolation with encoding (`{{! ... }}`). You could also try to encode all data and strip any possible javascripts server side when data is saved to be 100% sure you won't get anything malicious

Additionally if you are using jquery methods remember to use `text` method to insert data rather then `html` as text will automatically encode it.

And I really recommend the doT! It's super fast and we've managed to make it play really nicely with requirejs

Comment: I'm using ejs+jst with backbone. Are text escaped correctly there per context?

Comment: ejs === slowest js templating ever - we've switched from that (and jmvc) to (backbone +) doT - speed difference was huge (check http://jsperf.com/dom-vs-innerhtml-based-templating/73) ! And no problems with escaping for now - though I guess you want to be able to use server side and client side rendering using same templates - we have only client side rendering in our project.

Comment: Thanks. I actually really hate this ejs.jst thing, wishing to just use _.template. I'm reading about doT. Any information about integration with backbone?

Comment: It was straight forward for us, we are using require js as well and we've written special plugin to handle loading templates and converting them to helper template methods on the fly. Are you using any dependency loaders?

Comment: I'm using sprcokets (assets pipeline).